# Put string url data to bitmap

Tags: android

I'm making a wallpaper application. In this full-screen image activity, this activity is getting data from previous activity by intent. Now  I want to set the image(that comes from URL) as wallpaper. This code is not working.

```
public class PhotoFullPopupWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity context;
    Bitmap bitmap=null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_image_view);

        ImageView fullScreenImageView =  findViewById(R.id.FullScreenImageView);
            final String url=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(url)
                    .into(fullScreenImageView);

            context=this;

            bitmap = getBitmap(url);



        Button setWallpaperButton = findViewById(R.id.setWallpaper);
        setWallpaperButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
        try {
            URL URL = new URL(bitmapUrl);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(URL.openConnection().getInputStream());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your error code and description.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hspcMjx7TS/
Here this is!

Comment: Please don't refer to external information (it tends to disappear - which makes the question useless for future visitors). Put all relevant information directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the code i used for setting the wallpaper

```
 public void setWallpaper(String url) {
    WallpaperManager myWallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
   Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                    intent.setDataAndType(getLocalBitmapUri(resource), "image/*");
                    intent.putExtra("jpg", "image/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                            intent, "Set as:"));

  }





private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "OP_Wallpaper_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: I have another activity for passing intent. url loaded into string. and now I want to set wallpaper from a url that comes up with string value

Comment: In your onclick function try to call setWallpaper(url)

Comment: This is my onClick events on previous activity code:
.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/2qPCMsfkSy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In your first activity, you should save the Bitmap to disk.
2. Then load it up in the next activity.

***Make sure to recycle your bitmap in the first activity to prime it for garbage collection.***

> In Activity 1:

```
try {
    //Write file
    String filename = "bitmap.png";
    FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

    //Cleanup
    stream.close();
    bmp.recycle();

    //Pop intent
    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    in1.putExtra("image", filename);
    startActivity(in1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> In Activity 2:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
try {
    FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about your code, here's my activity one's code :
@Click(R.id.imageView)
    public void onClick() {
        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(mContext, PhotoFullPopupWindow.class);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("url",mUlr);
        mContext.startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
    }